# Qt doesnt find the environement variable set in bash

Tags: bash, qt, ubuntu

I have a camera which I'm connecting to it thought its own APIs. To get a working code the camera manual has suggested to add these environment variables into the system.

I've set the following in the /etc/bash.bashrc

```
    export PYLON_ROOT=/opt/pylon3
    export GENICAM_ROOT_V2_3=${PYLON_ROOT}/genicam

    mkdir -p $HOME/genicam_xml_cache
    export GENICAM_CACHE_V2_3=$HOME/genicam_xml_cache

    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${PYLON_ROOT}/lib64:${GENICAM_ROOT_V2_3}/bin/Linux64_x64:${GENICAM_ROOT_V2_3}/bin/Linux64_x64/GenApi/Generic:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

when I run my qt code from terminal the code runs without any error. but When I run it from the Qtcreator it gives me the following error and terminate the program !

**`Environment Variable 'GENICAM_ROOT_V2_3' not found`**

I've added the environment variables code to /etc/profile too but the result were the same. why Qtcreator doesn't find my variables ?

.pro

```
QT       += core

QT       += gui

INCLUDEPATH += /opt/pylon3/include \
/opt/pylon3/genicam/library/CPP/include
LIBS += -L/opt/pylon3/lib64 \
-L/opt/GenICam_v2_3/bin/Linux64_x64 \
-L/opt/GenICam_v2_3/bin/Linux64_x64/GenApi/Generic \
-lgxapi \
-lpylonbase \
-lpylonbase-3.2.0 \
-lpylongigesupp \
-lpylonutility \
-lGCBase_gcc40_v2_3 \
-lGenApi_gcc40_v2_3 \
-llog4cpp_gcc40_v2_3 \
-lLog_gcc40_v2_3 \
-lMathParser_gcc40_v2_3 \
-lXerces-C_gcc40_v2_7 \
-lXMLLoader_gcc40_v2_3


TARGET = VLPR
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv
```

Mainwindow.cpp

```
 MainWindow::MainWindow(QObject *parent) :QObject(parent)
{
    Initialize_Cam();
}
void MainWindow::Initialize_Cam()
{
    MonoCamThr = new MonoCamThread(this);
    MonoCamThr->Stop_Disp = true;
    MonoCamThr->start();
    MonoCamThr->Stop_Disp = false;
}
```

Monocam.cpp

```
MonoCamThread::MonoCamThread(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
    try
    {
        //  List of cameras
        DeviceInfoList_t m_Devices; // Still empty

        //  Create the unique transport layer factory object
        //  ... create the transport layer object
        //  ... create and initialise Cameras
        CTlFactory& TlFactory = CTlFactory::GetInstance();
        ITransportLayer *pTl = TlFactory.CreateTl( Camera_t::DeviceClass() );
        if ( ! pTl )
        {
            throw GenericException(
                "Failed to create transport layer!", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        }

        // Get all attached cameras and exit if no camera is found
        m_Devices.clear();
        if ( 0 == pTl->EnumerateDevices( m_Devices ) )
        {
            throw GenericException(
                "No camera present!", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        }
        if(m_Devices.size()<2)
        {
            while(1)
            {
                 qDebug() << "Number of Cameras are less than 2 .... \n" ;
            }
        }

            qDebug() << "Number of Cameras are: "<<m_Devices.size()<<" \n" ;
            // Restrict number of used camera
            size_t nCameras = 2;

            // Create all camera devices and set up the grab threads

            if(pTl->CreateDevice( m_Devices[0])->GetDeviceInfo().GetModelName())
            MonoCamera = new Camera_t( pTl->CreateDevice( m_Devices[1]) );


            MonoCamera->Open();

            MonoCamera->PixelFormat.SetValue( PixelFormat_Mono8 );
            MonoCamera->OffsetX.SetValue( 0 );
            MonoCamera->OffsetY.SetValue( 0 );
            MonoCamera->Width.SetValue( MonoCamera->Width.GetMax() );
            MonoCamera->Height.SetValue( MonoCamera->Height.GetMax() );
    }
    catch( GenericException &e )
    {
        qDebug() << "****  An exception occurred! Desription is: " << "\n"<< "    " << e.GetDescription() << "\n";
    }

}

void MonoCamThread::run()
{
    while(!Stop_Disp)
    {
//since this part of code never runs I didn' put the code for it ....
}
}
```

there are other cpp files but they run after camera initialization. I fixed this error once six month ago by adding GENICAM_ROOT_V2_3 PATH location to a system file in ubuntu like  .bashrc or .profile but I don't remeber the file name right now !! :((

P.S
Don't forget that this code runs in terminal and works fine ... the only problem is that Qt doesn't find the specified variable location !!!

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: my code consist of 14 cpp files and 15 hpp files !!! what do you mean exactly by showing my code ?

Comment: [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)

Comment: @PsP Post relevant code where you get error.

Comment: @PsP, try to start QtCreator from the terminal too.

Comment: I've added the code right now ...

Comment: You have not added any relevant code. Please do read the SSCCE link above. It is essential for helping.

Comment: Did you relog into your X-Session? Does Qt-Creator import the rest of the environment variables correctly? Check the Project->Run->Environment section. Check use build environment or set up the Paths manually in there.

Comment: `CONFIG += console` does not make sense in a GUI application. Remove that. Try to remove `CONFIG -= app_bundle`, too.

Comment: @SebastianLange I've also rebooted the system but I didn't get any answer

Comment: `QT += core` and `QT += gui` are unnecessary, too. "core" and "gui" are added by default. Remove them, too.

Comment: @lazlo okay I'll read the post right now ... the run time error is in the monocam.cpp file in the if(pTl->CreateDevice( m_Devices[0])->GetDeviceInfo().GetModelName()) line ... and shows the error and exits !

Comment: @LaszloPapp I've added those because I will load my GUI after the initialization. I run the initialization before Qt gui configuration because I wanted to make sure where the problem lies and which line does exactly give me the error

Comment: Still, they do not make sense. Just remove them.

Comment: Please check if Projects->Execution->Environment does include your variables. I remember QtCreator (early Qt5/QtCreator2.x) releases having sometimes trouble resolving Variables. But these Problems would be shown in the Runtime-Environment-Settings of your application.

Comment: @SebastianLange Waooo thanks  ... I've edited the variable PATH and it did worked ... all was because of environment settings of qtcreator ... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Qt with a similar cam. I've set "Run settings" like you can see in this image.

[image]

Comment: This is just a band-aid to the actual problem